# ASP.NET Build Images Links Dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website that has product images on an external server.  I have code that tests to see if the image exists like (pseudo code):

```
DynamicString = FunctionThatCreatesDynamicString()

' DynamicString = "http://external_server/path/to/file1.jpg"

If ImageExists(DyanmicString) = StatusCode.200 Then  
  ' Embed link in ASP.NET page  
Else  
   ' Embed not found image in ASP.NET page  
End If
```

My code builds fine and appears to execute.  The problem occurs when I attempt to view the external link in a browser, the image appears properly (I have to authenticate first, but that's OK considering I'm on an internal network and this app will be used internally).

However, when I attempt the view the source in my generated HTML page, I am seeing the image to the "Not Found" image when I *know* the image is there.

I compared all the characters in my dynamically assembled to the external link and all the characters are matching up correctly.

I'm wondering if the authentication has anything to do with why the image is not rendering properly on my rendered HTML.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was the authentication to the images.  I tried and was able to use a completely different approach.  But thanks for the tip tangurena.